# JSON API relationship with meta information

Tags: api, json-api

I have an entity `contract` with relationship `contract_contacts` that should be presented in **JSON API** format.

To be more clear here's the structure of my entities:

**Contract**

- id
- name

**ContractContact**

- contract_id
- contact_id
- type
- comment

**Contact**

- id
- name

Possible JSON API output will look like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "contracts",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Contract 1"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "contacts": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "contract_contacts",
                        "id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "contract_contacts",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is not good enough - you have to create additional resource for relation where you will store your contact and comment with type. You have to include with 2 levels deep to get you contact fields. Also in this case to create `contract` frontend should work with both resources:

1. Create contract contact and get id
2. Then Create contract with relationship
   with id from above

The second approach is seems *hacky* to me because it will use `meta` and it's up to you how to use it. Example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "contracts",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Contract 1"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "contacts": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "meta": {
                            "comment": "comment 1",
                            "type": 1
                        },
                        "type": "contacts",
                        "id": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "meta": {
                            "comment": "comment 2",
                            "type": 2
                        },
                        "type": "contacts",
                        "id": "11"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach will simplify the mess with api requests that was in previous example.

But is that correct to POST/PUT/PATCH with meta fields as they are not supposed to be changed from client (or supposed to be)? I'm confused with this part.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship that you are describing is often referred to as a *has-many-through* relationship: A `contract` has a many `contacts` through a `contract_contacts`. These is defined as a relationship that links two resources through an intermediate resource.

[JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) does not provide first-level support for these kind of relationship. You should instead model them through separate resources as described by you as your first option. This allows you to create, modify and delete your intermediate resource in the same way as any other resource. Doing so reduces the complexity as the intermediate resource is just another resource type as any other.

You mentioned two problems with doing so:

1. > You have to include with 2 levels deep to get you contact fields.

   This is true but shouldn't be an issue. `include` query parameter allows your client to sideload resources any many level deep as it needs. The response document might be a little bit bigger than it would be if the information of the intermediate resource is stored on the relationship itself but that shouldn't be relevant in production after gzip.
2. > Also in this case to create contract frontend should work with both resources:
   >
   > 1. Create contract contact and get id
   > 2. Then Create contract with relationship with id from above

   This is true and a serious limitation of the current stable version of JSON:API specification (v1.0). It's not directly related to *has-many-through* relationships so. It's a general limitation of the specification, which does not support creating, modifying and/or deleting more than one resource with one request.

   An official [Atomic Operations extension](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1437) is proposed for v1.1 of the specification to address that limitation. It's very likely that these one or a similar proposal will be included in the upcoming version.

It might be tempting to store the information of the intermediate model as meta data on the relationship. But doing so will introduce serious limitations which for I would strongly recommend to not take that path:

1. The JSON:API specification does not cover changing meta data. You would need to introduce your own specification to create or update these meta data.
2. Client-side libraries for the JSON:API specification do not expect such information to be available as meta data of the relationship. It's very likely that the consumers will have a hard time processing the information.
3. Storing information of the intermediate resource would lock you into using [resource linkage](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links) to express relationship information in a resource document. You would not be able to use [related resource links](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links). These may introduce serious performance issues as resource linkage requires to always lookup the IDs of related resources in the database, which is not required if using related resource links.